# Ionic 2 cannot upload project

Tags: ionic2, ionic-cli, ionic-cloud

I am new to Ionic 2 and try to upload project to ionic cloud behind a proxy server. I followed the setup steps, https://docs.ionic.io/setup.html, but there is a connection error as below,
[image: connection error]

I supposed it was caused by proxy server. I just wonder if anyone know to solve the issue.

Thanks,
Sean

Answer (score 0):

You need to set proxies in **ionic.config.json**.

```
proxies: [{
"path": "/api/",
"proxyUrl": "https://test.com/"
}],
```